# Cannot find -ltk ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tk-toolkit

I got an error when try to run make VERSION=full. I share the picture of the command here.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I need to install here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the photo as text. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/68587)

Comment: What are you trying to build? Give us some more context, please. Most software has build instructions that tell you what dependencies are needed and how to install them.

Comment: Ubuntu : `sudo apt install tcl-dev tk-dev` → Provides `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/{ libtcl.so, libtk.so }`

Answer (score 0):

Please check weather tk and tcl libraries are installed,
or the directories they are installed are linked with -L.